# Add days with business hours

Tags: apex

I want to add x number of days in a date with respect to my business hours.
This is my code

I used

> add(businessHoursId, startDate, intervalMilliseconds)

This is the snippet of code:

```
cNew.TAT_Target_DateTime_for_Pending__c = BusinessHours.add(cBHid, DateTimeNow, Math.abs(myTat.PendingTATms__c.intValue()));
```

> cBHid = is my business hoursid
>
> DateTimeNow = system.now
>
> myTat.PendingTATms__c = custom setting data

I asserted it and it returned scientific notation

view image
[image]

is there any way that I can add the milliseconds without exceeding the size of the intervalmilliseconds?

Comment: looks like your `assert` expected value is empty. Can you show more of your code please?

Answer (score 2):

`intValue` is limited to a maximum of 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1), resulting in a total expressed time of about 24.8 total days; if your business hours were 24 hours, you'd get about 3 weeks and 3 days before you rolled over. Instead, you will likely want to use `longValue`, which has twice as many bits (2<sup>63</sup>-1), resulting in a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, or a total of about 292,277,024 years in total time.

```
cNew.TAT_Target_DateTime_for_Pending__c = 
    BusinessHours.add(cBHid, DateTimeNow, Math.abs(myTat.PendingTATms__c.longValue()));
```